# How to checkout commits with fewer source files than the current commit

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am working on a C++ project with a primary task and several extension tasks, and using git for version control. When showing the project to others, it is useful to checkout a certain commit (tagged as 'primary') to demonstrate the state of the project at completion of the primary task. This is fine to show off the code, however my current version of the project has source files not present in 'primary', so they are no longer present when 'primary' is checked out. Trying to build the project generates an error complaining about the missing source files, shown at the bottom.

The files added to git are source_1.cpp, source_2.cpp, additional_source_file.cpp (not present in 'primary') and header.h, and presumably vs has a problem because the checkout does not update any of the project files that tell the project which source files to look for.

I guess that to fix the problem I need to add at least one more file to those tracked by git. Which files are these, or have I misdiagnosed the problem?

The workaround I currently use is to manually remove additional_source_file.cpp from the project, then re-add it when I checkout more recent commits.

Here is the error:

> Error  C1083   Cannot open source file: '........\a\b\project\additional_source_file.cpp': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All files required to build / run the project *at that point in time* should exist in your `primary` commit.

> *my current version of the project has source files not present in 'primary', so they are no longer present when 'primary' is checked out*

If you discard or stash all of your local changes (with `git stash`), you should have exactly the same code that exists at your `primary` commit when you run `git checkout primary`. You can confirm this with `git status`.

If the project *still* does not build when it has the exact same code as `primary`, then `primary` is not stable, and you'll have to add the files manually. I would then recommend merging these changes back into the branch that `primary` is on, following [Git Flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow).

> *demonstrate the state of the project at completion of the primary task*

It sounds like you're wanting to demo a specific, individual feature. For this, your best bet would be feature branches. You would merge these feature branches back to your core `develop` branch when the feature is complete (and has been tested), though you can always checkout the latest commit of the branch at any point in time for demo purposes.

Assuming the demo reveals that additional work should be done on this feature, you can still continue to code against this branch, even *after* it has been merged back to `develop`; you'll just need a second merge further down the line.

Comment: "All files required to build / run the project at that point in time should exist in your primary commit." How would you determine these files? I could add every file created by vs to git, but it strikes me that there will be several that there aren't necessary to track, e.g. .log files

Answer (score 0):

The original answer was helpful in pointing me in the right direction.

I was originally unaware that there were standard .gitignore files: I found the specific file for Visual Studio [on the GitHub website](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore). As far as I can tell, this excludes all the annoying files that get updated each time the project is compiled.

After updating the .gitignore file, I used the following commands in the git bash to purge and re-add the files being tracked by git.

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
```

This fixes the problem, because it has added

> All files required to build / run the project